# Iterate over array by selected numeric index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

By only knowing the index of a desired array item, I'd like to know its key value. From the array below it should only return: 3 for example.

Ideally i'd also like the previous and next id's.

JSON

```
//array to search - JSON
var steps = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"}];
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="steps" data-index="2">Step</a> 
 <!-- Data-index is the numeric index of the desired item -->
```

JQuery

```
$(document).on('click','.steps', function() {
  clickedindex = $(this).data('index');
  //return the ID value here.
});
```

Here's my pen: https://codepen.io/omarel/pen/eeyXmW

Comment: Cyclic or should previous/next be empty?

Comment: In the example above, previous/next shouldn't be empty.

Comment: what problems are you having doing so? You clearly seem to know how array indexing works

Comment: Jonas' question is of course about how it would work in boundary cases, not just in the example. I suppose you want a solution that works in other cases as well?

Comment: @charlietfl fetching the ID property from the array based on only numeric index. and also pulling the property of the previous and next.

Comment: `steps.slice(clickedindex - 1, clickedIndex + 1)`

Comment: @JonasW. I would need the property ID from the array. This would return only the numeric index?

Comment: @omar no, that returns the array that you show in your expected results and you still haven't isolated what your problem is doing this yourself. Lots of ways to do it

Comment: @charlietfl that's the array to search not the expected array.

Comment: Then you need to explain this whole issue a lot better. What do you plan to do with the results? Take a few minutes to read through [ask] and [mcve]. So far you omitted at least 3 things, a real problem statement, expected results, and an actual question

Comment: By only knowing the numeric index 2 of the array. Id' like to search the json array and grab the id's 1,3 and 4 from the array placing them in variables.

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you I edited my question trying to simplify the problem and expected result

Comment: @charlietfl I should get 1,3 and 4 because that's the value of the key stored in the array which is what I need. The only way I can search the array is by knowing the numeric index of the desired elements.

Comment: Well that's what the `slice()` above gets you...then do whatever you need to with he results. Still not clear what you need to do with those results. But result[0].id would be the previous ID assuming you aren't at index 0 to start...which you haven't explained what you want to do with either

Comment: Ah!! yes it does :) Thank you @JonasW. and charlietfl

Comment: @charlietfl oh but this is returning the entire item. I just need the value of the ID property for the items

Comment: I just showed you how to get an ID from that array

Answer (score 0):

**This would be the answer.** (put together based on some of the direction received in comments)

This will return the value of the key labeled ID from the array element, by iterating over the array using only the desired index value.

Array to Iterate over.

```
var steps = [{"id":"1","a":"a"},{"id":"3","b":"b"},{"id":"4","c":"c"}];
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click','.steps', function() {
  clickedindex = $(this).data('index');
  //return the key value of "id" key.

   //answer
   currentstep = steps[clickedindex];
   console.log(currentstep["id"]); 

});
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/omarel/pen/eeyXmW?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Array is 0-base, so in your example, index 2 is pointing to id 4.  Assuming you meant data-index=1, and previous and next are not empty, then this could solve your issue, if I understood your question right:

```
var prev, current, next; 
$(document).on('click','.steps', function() {
    clickedindex = $(this).data('index');
    prev = steps[clickedindex - 1].id;
    current = steps[clickedindex].id;
    next = steps[clickedindex + 1].id;
    console.log(prev + ' ' + current + ' ' + next ); 
});
```

You can use prev, current and next for whatever you need.